# JQuery DatePicker and ThemeRoller Are Clashing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker, themeroller

I've made a page (ASP.NET MVC3 and razor view) with a working JQuery datepicker.  Or at least it works until I switch my theme with the [themeswitcher widget](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher).  With the theme switched, I then bring up the date picker, and the widget has a heading something like this:

```
Prev Next
August
...as usual...
```

Unfortunately within about a second, the heading becomes corrupted; The 'Prev Next' text is superimposed with an image ribbon of left, right, up, down arrows.  The datepicker works correctly, but its header is jumbled text and images.  I thought perhaps my own site styling was conflicting with jquery, so I removed all of my styling entirely.  Yet the problem persisted.

When I compare my broken datepicker with a [sample on the jquery site](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), I see two of those same arrow images showing in the header, on either side of the month like this:

```
<- August ->
```

So I can see how the arrows were meant to be rendered.  I can also see the words "Prev Next" never appear.

To see how bare bones this example is, here is what my head element looks like:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
      function () {
          $("#MaxAge").datepicker();
          $('#switcher').themeswitcher();
      });
</script>
</head>
```

These bad results occur on both IE 9 and Chrome.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question.  I found it because I had the same issue.  The Themeswitcher seems to not be compatible with the datepicker.  I removed it and added themes to my site and the datepicker started displaying properly.

I suspect that you have to update the themes to the same version of jqueryui that you're using and in my case the themeswitcher was still serving up the last version.